# haproxy equivalent to .htaccess RewriteCond RewriteRule

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, haproxy

Right now I have in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(tiny.url) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works well. If I include a path with it then it translates it to the full url.

Ex:

- tiny.url/somefolder

then goes to

- www.example.com/somefolder

How do I do this in haproxy.

I have:
redirect location

```
http://www.example.com if { hdr(host) -i tiny.url }
```

This works but it doesn't allow a full path to be translated to the full url. How do I do that. I can't find anything in the haproxy help to help. I'm sure I just don't know what to type to find the help I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but I think you need to use `redirect` in [prefix mode](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-redirect%20prefix) something like this:

```
redirect prefix http://www.example.com if { hdr(host) -i tiny.url }
```

Hope that helps.